# Looking to find how to add resize button

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello:
   I have been experimenting with WPF this afternoon, Im wondering does anyone know how I can manually enable resizing ? I have my main windows set with the following properties which removes the close/min/max and resize;

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowStyle="None" Background="Maroon" ResizeMode="CanResize">
    </Window>
```

I have found how to add my own close/min/max buttons but have not found how to enable resizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
```

Comment: Why is it community wiki? May be I checked the checbox by mistake :(